# Android custom soft keyboard - how to clear edit text (commited text,...)

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-softkeyboard

I'm following this example: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/

I'm having trouble while adding a clear text button. I want a button which clear in-focus text. But since I re-focus a not-empty text, I don't know how to delete existed characters.
For example I have editText A and editText B.

```
focus A > commit "hello" > focus B > commit "world" > focus A > clear text in A >> FAIL
```

I still can delete text in A one by one character by using:

```
    //keyEventCode = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL
    getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(
            new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyEventCode));
    getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(
            new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyEventCode));
```

But it's impossible to clear text A since text A length is unknown. In addition, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CLEAR doesn't work with above function.

Any suggestion may help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I did something like this:

```
InputConnection inputConnection = getCurrentInputConnection();

CharSequence currentText = inputConnection.getExtractedText(new ExtractedTextRequest(), 0).text;
CharSequence beforCursorText = inputConnection.getTextBeforeCursor(currentText.length(), 0);
CharSequence afterCursorText = inputConnection.getTextAfterCursor(currentText.length(), 0);
inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(beforCursorText.length(), afterCursorText.length());
```

Comment: I did it the same way in my app - but now I found out, that it does not work when some charactes are marked...

Answer (score 1):

How about you simply retrieve the view under focus using `getCurrentFocus()` (see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCurrentFocus%28%29)) and then call `myFocusedEditText.setText("")` (I assume your field is an EditText)?

Comment: I'm deploying custom soft keyboard:
class SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService 
so I cannot call getCurrentFocus(), it's not an activity.

Comment: `InputMethodService` runs on another process than the view connected to it, it's a system-wide service all apps can connect to obtain keyboard focus for text input.